# Possible to INSERT with no rows in VALUES?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know this question may be a bit esoteric, but is it anyway possible to create an `INSERT` statement with a `VALUES` clause that has no values?

```
INSERT myTable
(col1, col2)
VALUES
<no values>
```

I am generating the `INSERT` statements programmatically and I can solve this by having an `IF` check that will not generate the `INSERT`, but I am curious this `VALUES` statement can be thought of as a set. And sets may be empty...

there is nothing mentioned about empty sets in the documentation for: 
[Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

Comment: Make the fields nullable and use `NULL` ? It basically means *I have no idea* with a Gaellic shrug.

Comment: Why don't you just try this and see if it fails?

Comment: It does fail, I wondering if there is a syntax that would not fail :)

Comment: Yeah, I can't find a way to call the insert and insert nothing.

Comment: What you're trying to do is generate (what's going to be invalid) SQL and execute it to have it **not** insert anything? Stick with the idea of excluding that query using a conditional in the program logic - it makes much more sense. Otherwise you're merely executing an SQL query with error suppression which is never going to be tidy or correct.

Comment: Sometimes I just want to go to "the bottom" of things. I addition to using `VALUES` with `INSERT` I use the `VALUES` clause with `MERGE` or `SELECT`. Especially when doing `MERGE` I find that I might have a need to have a `VALUES` clause that is empty.

Comment: I went looking for this because I wanted to test run a complicated, syntactically valid INSERT before going and populating it with an onerous dataset.  So not totally esoteric.

Comment: It's a useful idea. One could have a very simple static SQL template and a very simple values generator. That instead of bunch of IFs. You can handle empty set as well as the trailing coma like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple syntactical solution, but you could work around the issue by making your row generator a little more complex.

You could rewrite the part that generates rows to replace the VALUES constructor with a set of

```
SELECT values
UNION ALL
SELECT values
UNION ALL
...
```

including an obligatory SELECT of this kind:

```
SELECT NULL, NULL, ... WHERE 1 <> 1
```

either at the beginning or at the end. That obligatory item will produce no rows and if it happens to be the only element, then the entire union will produce no rows and the INSERT statement will insert nothing.

If the VALUES constructor is preferable for some reason, you could modify your generator to include a `(NULL, NULL, ...)` item and wrap a query around the constructor:

```
INSERT INTO
  target_table (target_columns)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (VALUES
    (...),
    ...
    (NULL, ...)  -- obligatory element
  ) AS v (column_names)
WHERE
  some_of_the_columns IS NOT NULL
;
```

where *`some_of_the_columns`* should be chosen among the columns for which a `NULL` can never be generated. Again, if the `(NULL, ...)` row happens to be the only generated row in VALUES, the resulting query will insert nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The only usecase for this I can imagine is that you want to read forward through a large datastream and know at the end of a record whether there are values to insert or not. You can rewrite your 'insert values' to 'insert into select' and add a condition at the end that will prevent an insert.

```
insert into myTable(col1, col2)
select null, null
where 1 = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Set theory recognizes an empty set but an insert values does not

Couple possible options:
Insert nulls and have an insert trigger that voids the insert
Insert nulls and have a view that excludes them

Answer (score 0):

In short, your code is fine except that you are using pseudo code.  This is what it should look like:

```
INSERT into myTable
(col1, col2)
VALUES
(null, null)
```

This will work perfectly fine as long as your columns are set to accept NULLs
You might want to consider getting an auto-increment ID field in there so you can identify these new row later.

Comment: @Aツ Null is not junk.  A count of null my be a valid metric.

Comment: Sorry, records with (only) null values are junk. True, you could count null rows but you would count including junk ;)

Comment: There are lots of reasons you would insert NULL values.  A placeholder for future updates, is the most obvious.  Which I why I suggested adding in an ID field.  So the entire friggin row isn't empty.

Comment: @m0n0ph0n So you don't know how exclude null values from a count? select count(*) from table where col1 is not null  or just select count(col1) from table

Comment: @durb sure it makes sense to have nullable fields according to db design. I just wanted to say that in his specific case, inserting a row with null values only does not make sense, just in order to not throw an error.

Comment: @Blam thanks I know how to count or exclude the null values. My point was just to prevent garbage data to be created.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate inserts by select statements.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2)
SELECT FROM otherTable WHERE condition
```

If the select returns no row, no record is inserted and no exception is thrown. Btw. on larger record counts this is massively faster that creating single row insert statements.

Comment: This has nothing to do with inserting values.   OtherTable may not even contain the values.

Comment: I understood that question was to know if it is possible to treat the values as a set, and the sub-select is such a set of data.

Comment: "INSERT statement with a VALUES"  VALUES is not a select not sub-select.  There is no VALUES in your answer.

Comment: Ok true. But it is still a valid statement. My intention was just to give another thought to the idea of the original question. If the VALUES is strictly needed, my simple answer would be: No this is not possible, do the conditional check.

Answer (score -2):

You could fill the columns with default data. Maybe 0 for int, empty Strings for text and so on. Otherwise you could make the columns nullable and fill them with null value. It depends on what you define as empty.

Comment: Empty in this case is zero rows inserted, so not default values. I know this is a corner case